# Drivers for IBALL Pen Digitizer 8068U in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, wacom

I own iball pen digitizer 8068U. The detailed specification for the product can be found in [this link](https://www.iball.co.in/Product/Technology-Accessories/Pen-Digitizer/PD-8068U/11218).
When I connect this tablet to my laptop it gets detected automatically. However, the mouse pointer does not move and for example if my browser is open this pen presses the back button of the browser. I have tried to follow the procedure listed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TabletSetupWizardpen). But I failed to configure this device. I would appreciate if someone could help me out by providing a detailed steps on how to set up this tablet in Ubuntu 19.04

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I am unable to create proper tags due to reputation points. I would appreciate if someone changes the tags properly.